# Symfony 5 (Including 4) using Gedmo Doctrine Extension for SoftDelete

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony5

I have tried to use soft delete (Using gedmo/doctrine-extensions) for some Entities in Symfony 5, and got some troubles:

> Listener "SoftDeleteableListener" was not added to the EventManager!

> Compile Error: App\Entity\Admin and Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity define the same property ($deletedAt) in the composition of App\Entity\Admin. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible. Class was composed

This is what I tried, and it runs well

1. Install gedmo/doctrine-extensions

   ```
    composer require gedmo/doctrine-extensions
   ```
2. Add column deleted_at to the table what you want to use soft delete (Use migration or add manually)
3. Add config to config/packages/doctrine.yaml

   ```
    filters:

        softdeleteable:

        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter

        enabled: true
   ```
4. Add config to config/services.yaml

   ```
    gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ '@annotation_reader' ] ]
   ```
5. Add Gedmo and use SoftDeleteableEntity to Your Entity

   ```
    <?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;

     /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AdminRepository::class)
     * @ORM\Table(name="admins")
     * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false, 
     hardDelete=false)
    */
    class Admin implements UserInterface
    {
        use SoftDeleteableEntity;
        ….
    }
   ```
6. And finally, use delete function as usual, the column deleted_at will be updated

   ```
    /**
     * @param Admin $admin
     */
     public function delete(Admin $admin)
    {
        $this->_em->remove($admin);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
   ```

**Note**:
Do not need to add `deletedAt` field, method `getDeletedAt` and `setDeletedAt` to Your Entity

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP Format (config/services.php) instead of YAML, change step 4 to the following.

```
$services->set("gedmo.listener.softdeleteable")
->class(\Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener::class)
->tag(name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber', attributes: ["method" => "setAnnotationReader", "connection" => "default"])
->args([service('doctrine.orm.metadata.annotation_reader')])
;
```